# No EJB receiver available for handling using Apache Camel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, apache-camel

I am invoking an EJB which is deployed in Jboss jboss-as-7.1.1.Final. Below is piece of code i am using to invoke and EJB.

```
private void sendRequest() { 
            String camelID = "jbossejb"; 
            Exchange furExchange = null; 
            Message msg = null; 
            final Employee employee = new Employee(); 
            ProducerTemplate pProducerTemplate = getProducerTemplate(); 
            Endpoint endPoint = springCamelContext.getEndpoint("jbossejb"); 
            Future<Exchange> futurexchange = (Future<Exchange>) pProducerTemplate 
                            .asyncSend(endPoint, new Processor() { 
                                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
                                            exchange.getIn().setBody(employee); 
                                    } 

                            }); 


            System.out.println("futurexchange:" + futurexchange); 
            try { 
                    furExchange = futurexchange.get(15000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (ExecutionException e) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (TimeoutException e) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

            if (furExchange.getException() == null) { 
                    msg = furExchange.getOut(); 
                    String messageId = furExchange.getIn().getMessageId(); 
                    System.out.println("In Camel MessageID -:" + messageId); 
                    msg = furExchange.getOut(); 
                    System.out.println("Message:" + msg); 
            } else { 
                    Exception ex = furExchange.getException(); 
                    ex.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    }
```

JNDI details are below

```
<bean id="ejb" class="org.apache.camel.component.ejb.EjbComponent">  
    <property name="properties" ref="jndiProperties" />  
</bean>  
<util:properties id="jndiProperties">  
  <prop    key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://localhost:4447</prop>  
      <prop key="jboss.naming.client.ejb.context">true</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">jboss7</prop>  
    <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">password</prop>  
</util:properties>
```

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown with the stack trace below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:MappedEJBModule,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@508894e3 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584) 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119) 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) 
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.receiveEmployee(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407) 
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278) 
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251) 
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166) 
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105) 
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71) 
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) 
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) 
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:73) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:378) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:346) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:242) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:346) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:184) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate$13.call(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:612) 
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate$13.call(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:610) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am able to receive the response when the EJB is deployed in any other Application Servers(IBM Websphere and Weblogic).

Please let me know what is causing issue in Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Verify that in your jndi properties the property jboss.naming.client.ejb.context has value true (but it should be a boolean true, not String 'true') - I think that when setting this property in xml it will be interpreted as String, which may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Property 'jboss.naming.client.ejb.context' value is already set to Boolean true in JNDI properties but still the same.